# Access audio output in iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio, pcm

I want to get audio data from output device in iOS in PCM format. I want perform FFT on the output audio and show information. Can you please provide me links to sample source code or tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API on iOS for access to the audio output device.   An app has access to any PCM audio data that the app itself plays.  See the API for the RemoteIO Audio Unit.